# How do I enable logging for ssh log in attempts?

Tags: ssh, macos

I have enabled remote logins via SSH on my Mac. But how do I enable logging of all log in attempts? And where is the log?

My `/etc/sshd_config` has this content:

```
# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
```

Answer (score 1):

Login attempts are logged in `/var/log/system.log`

You'll be able to browse and filter for them through the Console.